# Android image share from internal storage not working

Tags: java, android, image

I have a functionality to share a particular image to Instagram, the image is downloaded from HTTP and stored in internal storage. When I try to share the image, it fails doing that.

```
// Store bitmap to image
String path = context.getFilesDir() + "/MyApp";
File imageFolder = new File(path);

if (!imageFolder.exists()) {
  imageFolder.mkdirs();
}

File imageFile = new File(path, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

if (!imageFile.exists()) {
  imageFile.createNewFile();
}

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
out.flush();
out.close();

// Share image
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageFile.toURI().toString()));
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
```

It doesn't throw any exception, but when instagram opens it says failed loading image and then gets closed.

Comment: Have you tried sharing it to any other App?

Comment: getFilesDir() is a private directory for your app. No other app has access. Try getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: You should get a FileUriExposedException not using a FileProvider.

Comment: @blackapps `getExternalFilesDir` will look for directory in external storage or internal storage?

Comment: Look at the function name. What does it tell you?

Comment: FYI: getExternalFilesDir() has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use file sharing you need to use a File Provider:

> To securely offer a file from your app to another app, you need to
>   configure your app to offer a secure handle to the file, in the form
>   of a content URI. The Android FileProvider component generates content
>   URIs for files, based on specifications you provide in XML

Please check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing) for an example